# Laravel request validation (requests with arrays)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am developing an app using Laravel and VueJs. I have used the below form validation rules:

```
public function rules()
{
  $rules = [
    'id.*'=>'required|integer',
    'job_id.*'=>'required|integer',
    'satisfied.*'=>'nullable',
    'client_comments.*'=>'nullable',
    'improvements.*'=>'nullable',
    'rating.*'=>'integer|max:10|min:0'
  ]; 
  return $rules;
}
```

Further, I am sending the below axios request to the Laravel controller. However, the validation is not working. Could somebody can help?

The request comes to the Laravel controller as below:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:7 [
    "client_comments" => null
    "id" => 34
    "improvements" => null
    "job_id" => 1
    "quality_cycle_id" => 14
    "rating" => "10"
    "satisfied" => null
  ]
  1 => array:7 [
    "client_comments" => null
    "id" => 35
    "improvements" => null
    "job_id" => 3
    "quality_cycle_id" => 14
    "rating" => "9"
    "satisfied" => null
  ]
]
```

I just used so many efforts to resolve this problem, but none of these worked. In the same application, I have put so many validations for single request. But this request is coming as an arrays inside array as above.

Appreciate, if somebody help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to validate like this:

```
 $request->validate($request, [
          '*.id'=>'required|integer',
          '*.job_id'=>'required|integer',
          '*.satisfied'=>'nullable',
          '*.client_comments'=>'nullable',
          '*.improvements'=>'nullable',
          '*.rating'=>'integer|max:10|min:0']);
```

It works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Your field is inside of array not an array. It work for array of  inputs `id[], job_id[], etc..`

Try this,

```
public function rules()
{

 $rules = [

          '*.id'=>'required|integer',
          '*.job_id'=>'required|integer',
          '*.satisfied'=>'nullable',
          '*.client_comments'=>'nullable',
          '*.improvements'=>'nullable',
          '*.rating'=>'integer|max:10|min:0'

        ]; 

        return $rules;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The request data should be in a specified filed like `items`, which you dump it out using

```php
dd($request->input('items'));
```

That prints an array. So to validate that array you could use these rules:

```php
public function rules()
{
  return [
    'items.*.id'=>'required|integer',
    'items.*.job_id'=>'required|integer',
    'items.*.satisfied'=>'nullable',
    'items.*.client_comments'=>'nullable',
    'items.*.improvements'=>'nullable',
    'items.*.rating'=>'integer|max:10|min:0',
  ];
}
```